# <CR> not recognized as variable in VIM vimrc using PuTTY

Tags: linux, vim, debian, keymap

**My code**

In my vimrc file I have added a key mapping to create new tabs.

```
map 1 :tabnew<CR>
```

**The problem**

However, when I press `1` in vim, it prints the ` variable as a string literal. I will have to press the return key to execute key mapped colon commands.

```
:tabnew<CR>
```

**Extra Information**

I am using PuTTY to connect to my Debian server.

**Thank you for helping me.**

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a special key notation. Do you have the "`<`" character in the output of "`:verbose set cpo?`" (with the question mark as part of the command)?

Comment: For that matter, what's the output of "`:verbose set compatible?`" (again, with the question mark as part of the command)?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes it is there in the output. `cpoptions=aAbBcCdDeEfFgHiIjJkKlLmMnoOpPqrRsStuvwWxXyZ$!%*-+<>
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/vim.vim` And `nocompatible`.

Comment: Okay, the `<` means that the special keycodes will _not_ be recognized in mappings.  You either need to make sure you are not running in compatible mode, or manually remove the `<` from 'cpoptions'.

Comment: Thanks! What would you suggest I do? And how do I change cpoptions? By the way, what do these two things mean? compatible and cpo?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I have edited my answer below, but you need to figure out why /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/vim.vim is changing that setting. It shouldn't be.  Also, Vim 7.2 is outdated, upgrade if you can.

Comment: I have no clue. I'm currently upgrading my packages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9840/discussion-between-user907560-and-heptite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you are running Vim in compatible mode, and if you have a `~/.vimrc` it should automatically be going into nocompatible mode.  Whatever the reason, I suggest you override it by adding this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:set nocompatible
```

The problem is that in compatible mode, many of Vim's extended feature set is disabled, including recognizing <...> notation in mappings as special key codes.

If doing `:set nocompatible` doesn't work, try manually setting 'cpoptions' to the Vim non-compatible default:

```
:set cpoptions=aABceFs
```

See:

```
:help 'compatible'
:help 'cpoptions'
```

(The single quotes are part of the command.)

***Edit:*** From the discussion in comments it appears your Vim install is broken and the system vim.vim ftplugin is overriding the 'compatible' or 'cpoptions' settings.  Upgrading from 7.2 to 7.3 may help.

Comment: I am not running compatible mode. The output says `nocompatible`.

Comment: If you are in nocompatible mode, the output of "`:set cpoptions?`" should not be including all the stuff you showed above. Something is very messed up.

Comment: Here is my /etc/vim/vimrc file. http://pastebin.com/W6i9BySv

Comment: Here is my ~/vimrc file. http://i41.tinypic.com/11w9dl4.png

Comment: It is still not working.

Comment: I suspect that's because /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/vim.vim is overriding it after your vimrc is loaded. Let me reiterate: This should NOT be happening. Your Vim install appears broken. Try upgrading to 7.3.

Comment: I'm using Debian Squeeze. 7.3 is only available for Wheezy. I will try reinstalling.